# in order followed by a sentence

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, paraphrasing, readability

Is this sentence correct?

> The matrix naming must be arranged in the order that they are supposed to be calculated.

I mean from the aspect of `in the order that`. I feel when someone reads this sentence at first they interpret the word `order` with meaning of `in order to` unless they read the sentence to the end. Then they realize it is about priority of matrices for naming(A, B, C, ...).

Comment: You're basically using "they" to refer to "the matrix naming", which, if it doesn't violate some rule, certainly doesn't sound right, since "naming" isn't obviously plural.  Maybe something along the lines of "The elements of the naming matrix must be arranged in the order in which the corresponding calculations are are to be performed."  (Though I'm sure one can do better.)

Comment: @HotLicks, no, here *they* refers to *the matrix* excluding *naming* only matrices are supposed to be calculated but not namings.

Comment: If *they* refers to *matrix* what's *naming* doing there??

Comment: And since when is "matrix" plural?

Comment: @HotLicks, I want to say *The matrix naming must be arranged in the order that matrices are supposed to be calculated.*

Comment: Are there multiple matrices or multiple elements in a single matrix?

Comment: And are the matrices calculated (ie, created), or are computations performed on them?

Comment: @HotLicks there are multiple matrices. They do exist in form of concept and size. However the element inside them are unknown until computation.

Comment: And what does it mean to "arrange naming"?

Comment: "The matrix names must be listed in the order that the corresponding matricies are to be calculated."

Comment: @HotLicks they must give names to matrices such as A, B, C, D, E, ... . matrix A is the matrix which is calculated first. B is the second calculated ....

Comment: The alphabetical naming of the matrices indicates the order in which they must be computed.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is OK for a native British English speaker. "In order that" (without "the") is a conjunction, similar to "in order to". The definite article "the" means that "order" is a noun in your sentence.

I think it would read better as "The matrix names must be arranged in the order that...". "The matrix names" is clearly an adjective + noun. It is not so clear what "matrix naming" is, until you have read the whole sentence.

Or, you could change it to something like "Arrange the matrix names in the order that they will be calculated."

Comment: Well, the sentence is unintelligible to this US English speaker.  There are multiple things wrong with it in terms of actually communicating the writer's meaning.  I read it and, speaking as a computer programmer, I have no idea what it's trying to say.

Comment: @HotLicks To me, the only problem with the sentence is that _naming_ should be _names_.

Comment: @Barmar - But the names aren't calculated.  They're about the only known quantity in the whole equation.

Comment: @HotLicks It would be helpful to see more context. I think that might make it clear that it's the matrixes that are being calculated, and we're arranging their names in the order that this must be done.